# Где ошибка, в моем коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я сделал задание, но сайт отказывается принимать его

[image: Вот задание]

Вот мой код:

```
a=int(input())
b=a
for i in range(a):
    b=b-1
    c=2**b
    if c>1 and c!=8 and c!=32 and c!=128 and c!=2:
        print(c, end=' ')
```

Comment: Но ведь программа работает неправильно, она абсолютно не соответствует условию задачи

Comment: А что именно???

Comment: По условию очевидно, что вы должны проверять чётность показателя степени, но в вашем коде никакой проверки чётности нет

Comment: Более того, если задать 11, то она выведет 512, что не соответствует условию

Comment: @andreymal ну почему же? Первая, третья, пятая и седьмая степени исключены «вручную» =)

Comment: Можете пожалуйста составить код. Я почти целый день убил на эту задачу. Но ничего не смог придумать

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать автору тестов, которые «не проходят»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что ваш код даст неправильный вывод (например для ввода 10 в нём отсутствует 1024).

1. Первая ошибка в том, что вы вводимое число *сразу же уменьшаете* командой `b=b-1`, *не глядя на то, если оно чётное или нет.*
2. Далее, вы вручную убираете *только* `8`, `32`, `128` а уже **нет** `512`, `2048`, и т.д. (бесконечное количество таких...).
3. Но и совсем нет в вашем коде вывода `0`, когда чётных степеней нету (требование задачи).

---

*Не нужно* вручную *уменьшать экспонент и* вручную *удалять нечётные степени, т.к. функция `range()` может это сделать за вас:*

```
n = int(input())

if n % 2 != 0:                 # когда n нечётное
    n = n - 1                  # уменьшим его, чтобы было чётным

for i in range(n, 0, -2):      # для чисел от n до 0 с шагом -2, т.е. только для чётных
    print(2 ** i, end=" ")     # вывод степени, но после того не новая строка, а пробел

if n < 2:                      # (тогда ни предыдущий цикл for ничего не вывел)
    print(0)                   # требование задачи
```

Answer (score 0):

До кучи можно побаловаться с битовыми операциями:

```
a=int(input())
if a < 2:
    print(0)
else:
    a &= 0xFFFFFFFE  #сбросили младший бит
    while a:
        print(1<<a)
        a -= 2
```

или так

```
else:
    a &= 0xFFFFFFFE
    b = 1 << a
    while (b > 1):
        print(b)
        b >>= 2
```